# Sorting in c++, without arrays

Tags: c++, sorting

I am new to c++, and I'm currently trying to do sorting. But no matter what I try it doesn't seem to work. I don't really have any experience with while, for loops, and arrays, and so I hope that In the end there is a way to do sorting without them.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;

void Sort(){
    cout << "Enter 4 numbers.";

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
    cin >> d;

    if (a < b){
        swap (b,a);
    }

    if (b < c){
        swap (c,b);
    }

    if (c < d){
        swap (d,c);
    }
}

int main () {
    Sort();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't avoid arrays simply because you don't want to learn how to work with them...

Comment: You should learn about loops and arrays and consider this the opportunity to do so.

Comment: You're going to have to use some sort of loop if you ever want to scale this up to sort more numbers. Try learning C++ basics more before trying to tackle this

Comment: With only four values, it should be easy to simulate your algorithm using pencil and paper.  Try "4 3 2 1" as your input and see what happens.

Comment: There are minimum **five** conditions,  not three, to be checked for sorting four arbitrary items. And this gets unmanageable past a dozen or so. Learn loops and arrays.

Comment: *and so I hope that In the end there is a way to do sorting without them.* -- Try to sort a hundred or a thousand numbers without using arrays (or some container) and loops.

Comment: Sorting is more difficult than loops and arrays. I suggest you learn loops and arrays first.

Comment: If you don't want to use loops and arrays you have to continue the processes manually. You have the smallest value in `d` now. Now you have to get the second smallest value in `c`. You simply have to repeat what you did again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that everyone has pounded the point of learning array management and loop control, I'l tell you what is actually wrong with your sorting operation. It's only partially sorting because your chosen comparisons and swaps are incomplete, and frankly based on educated naive guessing.

Sorting four arbitrary values descending without arrays can be done with a [**static sorting network**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). I'll not go into how they work, and the far, far more complex task of how to generate them (generators do exist, btw). Suffice it to say that John's comment about sorting being much, much more complicated than loops and arrays is spot-on, and infinite wisdom, and you should learn the latter first.

Regardless, see below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    if (!(std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if (a < b)
        std::swap(a, b);

    if (c < d)
        std::swap(c, d);

    if (a < c)
        std::swap(a, c);

    if (b < d)
        std::swap(b, d);

    if (b < c)
        std::swap(b, c);

    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Those comparisons and swaps are *not* arbitrary. They were chosen *specifically* because at each point along the algorithm, what you have in place in each variable is a direct reflection of the code before it. For only a few numbers, this is visually graspable. Once you cross about eight or so, things get very complicated, *very* quickly.

Your code is broken because you didn't actually consider what each step in your swap comparisons was doing, and what was left in the wake of prior steps. Though you *can* do this for smaller sets of items (optimized multi-phase sorting algorithms frequently employ static sorting networks for the smaller partitions), it is no excuse for avoiding learning sequence management with things like arrays and loop control. You'll use that knowledge the rest of your life, and in many more things than just sorting.

Answer (score 1):

> But no matter what I try it doesn't seem to work.

That's because you have simply sorted the smallest number into `d`.

The next step is to repeat what you have done for each of the next three numbers.

```
//What You did:
if (a < b){
    swap (b,a);
}

if (b < c){
    swap (c,b);
}

if (c < d){
    swap (d,c);
}

// You now have `d`.
// To sort this you need to do this 3 more
// times to get the other three values
if (a < b){
    swap (b,a);
}

if (b < c){
    swap (c,b);
}

if (c < d){
    swap (d,c);
}

// You now have d and c correct.
if (a < b){
    swap (b,a);
}

if (b < c){
    swap (c,b);
}

if (c < d){
    swap (d,c);
}

// You now have d c b correct.
if (a < b){
    swap (b,a);
}

if (b < c){
    swap (c,b);
}

if (c < d){
    swap (d,c);
}

// You now have d c b a correct. Sorted complete.
```

I would note that this is way easier if you simply use a loop. There is a lot less code to type. But what you have implemented here is a bubble sort for 4 values (with absolutely no optimizations) that you have unrolled. Now you can optimize this not all those swaps are required. But I think it best you learn about loops next.

Comment: If you have `d`, `c`, and `b` correct, then by definition, the only remaining `a` must also be correct ;)

Comment: @user2079303: I know. But that's an optimization. Just like not needing to re-test the ones that are already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

> But no matter what I try it doesn't seem to work.

It doesn't work because you don't sort the array enough. Those three swaps aren't sufficient for all inputs.

Now that you've attempted to invent a way to sort numbers, I would suggest researching existing algorithms. I recommend starting with teaching yourself bubble sort. Not because it's good - it's not - but because it is very intuitive, and in fact what you have written so far is the first "pass" of the bubble sort algorithm.

You can certainly implement bubble sort without loops or arrays, but it will be more tedious and error prone than using them.